# CPLEX binary_var_matrix gives values outside 0.0 and 1.0

Tags: cplex, docplex

I use

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
mdl = Model(name='itc_load_planning')
    Assignment = mdl.binary_var_matrix(orders, freights, name='Assignment')
...

ok = mdl.solve()
if ok:
    # mdl.print_solution()
    for index, dvar in enumerate(mdl.solution.iter_variables()):
        svar = dvar.to_string()  #Assignment_<orderid>_<freightid>
        val = dvar.solution_value #<--val is here
```

For the `val` most of the time is 1.0, on one occation I have the following values

```
0.9999999999996256 (for Assignment_406_454)
3.74408837266983e-13 (for Assignment_406_467)
```

where `orderid=406` supposed to have 1 result, obviously it's the first entry, but why CPLEX gives two solutions? Is this a bug? How to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

No its not a bug. This is entirely normal and expected behaviour for almost all solvers - they work to get a solution that satisfies all the constraints within a specified tolerance (something like 1e-6 to 1e-9). A value of 3.7e-13 is really really small so can be rounded down to zero, and 0.999999... is very close to 1 and so can be rounded up to 1. These 'errors' are about the same sort of scale as the  measuring the diameter of planet earth with an error of about the diameter of a single human hair.

There might theoretically be a small chance that the rounded values don't satisfy all the constraints - but I have never come across any case of that in almost 30 years using CPLEX and neither has anyone else that I have heard about.

If this is still not good enough for you, you can try getting the solution values from CPLEX, rounding these values and then re-solve your model with extra constraints fixing the variables to the rounded values to prove that the rounded solution really does satisfy all the constraints.

Comment: What if I have two constraints;
1- `.. <= .. + M*X`
2- `.. <= .. + M*(1-X)`
A small value affects the constraint.
The matter is if it tries all the values within the tolerance or not?